# Equivalant for onload and onclick?

Tags: javascript, onload

The proprietie `onclik` is obsolete. I use `addEventListener`, here is an example => `myVariable.addEventListener('click', myFunction);`

What is the equivalant for the proprietie `onload` ?

Comment: ```object.addEventListener("load", myFunction)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent is `document.addEventListener('load', function() {});`

Answer (score 1):

Its about a similar syntax

```
object.addEventListener("load", myScript);
```

Reference:

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

[2] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp